# IP Address Class issue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns, dns-zone

I took over a network but I am having trouble dealing with the IP class.
The IP range is 101.10.10.xxx
Everything works great, except for our website, which is hosted by a third party on their own server.
They have to manually edit the hosts file on local machines to enter the following or it wont work :
109.200.117.xxx    www.ourwebsite.com

Any machines outside the office can see the website as the DNS knows where to find it, but our internal DNS is not playing ball.

I have tried to edit the 2012 Server with the A Record by creating a www record but this is a hit and miss.

I looked at changing it to Class C but I can't change the IP range for the LAN because we have a lot of hardware supplied by various manufactures and trying to group them together to all change the IP is almost a no no  because they are based in Spain, New Zealand for example.

What is causing this problem and how can I resolve this without the massive IP address change ?

Thank you for any help given.

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking doesn't use network classes. Please let them rest in peace. It sounds like you need to see if you can fix your DNS (preferred), or implement hairpin routing (a kludge).

Comment: Can your internal machines browse to other sites? i.e. can those machines resolve DNS for other sites.

Answer (score 0):

The IP ranges don't overlap even if you're using a 255.0.0.0 subnet mask so there is no issue with your existing internal network range, you don't need to change anything there. That you can resolve this with a host file entry confirms this is a DNS problem and that is what you need to investigate.

The solution you've already tried of adding an A record to your DNS server is the correct one, you need to investigate why this is not working reliably.

I would suggest the following:

-Add the A record to your internal zone
-right click the DNS Server name in the DNS MMC and 'Clear Cache' (this is because DNS servers negatively cache answers)
-delete hosts file entry on a client
-run `ipconfig /flusdns` on client to flush the local dns cache
-run `nslookup www.ourwebsite.com` on client - confirm the correct IP is returned

On any clients not getting the correct IP returned from nslookup use `ipconfig /all` and confirm they are pointing to the correct DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

If the 101.10.10.x range is real: that range is allocated to Taiwan Mobile. You can't use public addresses without prior allocation and are likely to need renumbering - which isn't all that bad with DHCP. If you don't use DHCP, now is the time to start. It'll also make sure that all clients are using your internal DNS server.